# Importing empty columns from CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to import a dataset from a CSV file using Pandas. The problem is that I have some empty cells in the last 5 columns of the first few rows. These cells get populated later on. How do I import the entire dataset and not the non-empty columns only?

Comment: Would you mind importing the code you are using?  This gives us more to work with in terms of helping you.

Answer (score 1):

The empty cells should just be a series of commas in the csv file.

```
#write a data frame to csv
pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3],'B':[np.nan,4,5],'C':[np.nan,6,7] }).to_csv('/tmp/df.csv')

#I'm using iPython here, but however you want to view the df
!cat /tmp/df.csv 
,A,B,C
0,1,,
1,2,4.0,6.0
2,3,5.0,7.0

#read the df back in from CSV
pd.read_csv('/tmp/df.csv', index_col=0)
   A    B    C
0  1  NaN  NaN
1  2  4.0  6.0
2  3  5.0  7.0
```

Looking at the first (non-header) line of the CSV, you can see the blank cells are indicated by the commas with nothing after them.